# Customize Default Splash Screen of react-native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, splash-screen

Is there any way to remove the default Splash screen of react-native. Or Coustomize the Default Splash Screen. Like I want to a add a loading bar and fade effects in splash screen. And I want to create 2 splash screens for company & app. Is it possible to change the loading time?

Comment: Hi, you are using expo or only react-native?

Comment: @OscarVelandia I am using both of them... Expo & React-Native

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set just an image as splash, you can modify your app.json like [this](https://docs.expo.io/tutorial/configuration/),

If you want to do an animated splash, you can use the `'expo-splash-screen'`. I use this code one time. the most important part is the `preventAutoHideAsync().catch(console.warn);` that show the animation as the first component in the app, and in `hideAsync().catch(console.warn);` you continue the execution of your app.

```js
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import Home from '_screens/Home';
import Splash from '_screens/Splash';
import { preventAutoHideAsync, hideAsync } from 'expo-splash-screen';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

/* expo-splash-screen works fine but raise an exception because the managed expo workflow
 * use the old version of this library, however a fix was merged and probably in the next version of
 * expo this will be fixed, about this error https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/8067
 */
preventAutoHideAsync().catch(console.warn);

export type RootStackParamList = {
  Home: undefined;
};

export default function App(): JSX.Element {
  const [isLoadingSplash, setIsLoadingSplash] = useState(true);
  const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
  const init = (): void => {
    setTimeout(async () => {
      hideAsync().catch(console.warn);
      setIsLoadingSplash(false);
    }, 5000);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    init();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {isLoadingSplash && <Splash />}
      {!isLoadingSplash && (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
            <Drawer.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
            <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
          </Drawer.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change picture of default splash screen then consider this for android.

Goto `android\app\src\main\res\drawable`

and then change the picture `splashscreen_image.png`

You can edit `splashscreen.xml` there as well